# What is the difference between these two scenarios

Tags: probability, permutations

My text book says let there are n letters corresponding to n envelopes, and these n letters are places in those envelopes at random
Then probability that all letters are not in right place is $ 1 - \frac{1}{n!} $

And probability that no letters is in right envelop is
$ \frac{1}{2!}- \frac{1}{3!} +
  \frac{1}{4!}+.........+(-1)^n \frac{1}{n!} $

Is not the both scenarios same, all letters in wrong envelop and no letter in right envelop seems to be same meaning expressed differently.
I don't know what i am missing

Comment: "all letters are not in right place" means that some letters may be in right place.

Comment: No , that is wrong , @trueblueanil , "all letters are not in right place" means "all letters are in wrong place" , whereas "**NOT** all letters are in right place" means some letters may be in right place though some letter has to be in wrong place.

Comment: Compare with "all numbers are real" & "all numbers are not real" & "**NOT** all numbers are real" , @trueblueanil , that last Statement allows imaginary numbers & real numbers , whereas that middle Statement will not allow real numbers at all.

Comment: Alas, there are differences in how language is used in logic/syllogisms, and everyday usage.  The book has interpreted it as "not all...", That's why the answers differ.

Comment: Without any CONTEXT, I consider that 'all letters not in right place' means ... what you say.  I translate with your wording (all in wrong place) , but I keep in mind that maybe, it is not the good interpretation.  And when the context says clearly that question 2 is 'no letter in right place', I need to reevaluate the first sentence. And now, there is no doubt : today, in this specific exercice, "all not in the right place' means 'at least one wrong'.

Comment: We should not use Every-Day language in Math text Book , where Accuracy+logic are very necessary , @trueblueanil , which is why I state in my Answer that it is Poorly Worded. If we are allowed to Interpret Theorem , Statement , Question in Math text Book using Every-Day language , Various Country Citizens will get Various Conflicting Answers to the Same Question. **Here , OP is right , Scenarios are Same , text Book is wrong.** It is easy to fix , like I did in my Answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Confusion is valid , the text book may be Poorly ( wrongly ) worded.
You might want to put the Exact wordings in the Post.

Let the Envelopes be $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$.
Let the letters be $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$.

Condition $C_0$ : "not all letters are in right envelop" ( not given in the text Book )

Condition $C_1$ : "all letters are not in right envelop" ( given in text Book )
Condition $C_2$ : "no letter is in right envelop" ( given in the text Book )

Here you can see the Different Assignments :
A0 : $(E_1,l_1),(E_2,l_2),(E_3,l_3),(E_4,l_4)$
A1 : $(E_1,l_1),(E_2,l_3),(E_3,l_4),(E_4,l_2)$
A2 : $(E_1,l_1),(E_2,l_2),(E_3,l_4),(E_4,l_3)$
A3 : $(E_1,l_2),(E_2,l_3),(E_3,l_4),(E_4,l_1)$

A1 & A2 & A3 will match $C_0$ , which will allow some letters in right envelope , though there must be some letter in wrong envelope.
A3 matches is $C_1$ & $C_2$ , which will prevent even 1 letter to be in right envelop , hence A1 will not match.

Statements given :
"all letters are not in right envelop"
"no letter is in right envelop"

You are right : Both are Same , Probability is Same : the longer Calculation you have given.

What that Text Book wanted to state : "not all letters are in right envelop" , where the Probability is not Same : The shorter Calculation you have given.
Basically , we have $1$ way to put in Correct order , $n!$ total ways , hence $n!-1$ wrong ways , hence Probability is easy to Calculate.

The other Case is slightly harder to Calculate.
It is a Derangement Problem. It matches the longer Calculation you have given.

More Detail : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement